# Plotting multiple series in a line graph in excel with different time values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have the following data:

```
Time    v
0   5.4
5   4.5
10  5.3
15  6
20  5.1
25  7.4
30  6.7
40  6.1
50  6.9
60  5.9
70  6.1
80  6.2

Time    v
0   4.7
5   4.8
10  5.5
15  6.1
20  6.8
25  7.5
30  7.9
40  8.2
45  9.2
50  9.9
55  8.6
60  8.4
65  7.1
70  7
75  6.3
85  5.2

Time    v 
0   5.1
5   5.4
10  5.7
15  6.7
20  6.8
25  7.6
30  7.4
35  6.3
40  6.6
45  6.3
50  6.9
55  6.8
60  6.2
65  6.2
75  5.7
85  6.1
95  5.6
105 5.4

Time    v 
0   4.5
4   5
8   5.4
12  5.6
16  6.2
20  5.9
24  6.3
28  6
32  7.3
36  6.4
40  5.7
44  5.4
48  5.4
```

And each section represents a separate line that I want to be plotted on a graph. As you can see, the time values are **different** for each recordings and I am not able to figure out a way to embed all these different sections into their individual lines in a excel line graph.

Any help?

(I am using both Google Docs and Microsoft Excel spreadsheet)

Answer (score 10):

Another alternative is to use an Excel Scatter plot, which lets you choose different sets of time (X) values for each data set plotted:

[image]

Comment: Rather than saying what he should be using, do you have instructions on how? Where is the option to configure the X-Axis in this specific way?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell On Excel 2010, when I add or edit a series, I can specify a name, the series X values, and the series Y values. So there's really nothing to configure to make it work. If you want to change the range of an axis, just double click it.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest rearranging your data as on the left in the image below (if a chart as on the right is something like your requirement!):

[image: SU606489 example]